# $_GETで条件が複数ある場合のphp側での記述方法

Tags: php

初歩的な質問で恐縮でございます。

Phpの$_GETに関するご質問でございます。以下のようなURLであれば、phpの記述でそれぞれx、yという設定にしたいと考えております。

xxxxx.com?&category_id=1
x

xxxxx.com?&category_id=1?&list_id=1
y

以上の様なケースの場合、上のケースは

```
if($_GET['category_id'] == 1 )  {
    x
}
```

なのですが、下のケースの場合、つまり、（category_idが1でなおかつlist_idが1の場合）どの様な記述にすべきかお教え願いませんでしょうか。

```
if($_GET['category_id'] == 1 ・・・・・){
    y
}
```

Comment: 誤記でしょうか？　`xxxxx.com?&category_id=1?&list_id=1`→`xxxxx.com?category_id=1&list_id=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

category_idが1でなおかつlist_idが1の場合は以下の記述になるかと思います。
”かつ”の条件は論理演算子の`&&`で記述します。

```
if($_GET['category_id'] == 1 && $_GET['list_id'] == 1){
    y
}
```

Comment: 皆様、大変感謝いたします。期待通りの結果になっております。同様の条件を増やしたい場合は&& $_GET['']を増やしていけばよく、可能な限り増やせると考えて宜しいのでしょうか。